# mysql query in procedural php isn't returning single field

Tags: php, mysqli

Trying to retrieve a single field from a mysql table. Here's the PHP:

```php
if ($signatureDAT) {
    mysqli_query($dragonden, "INSERT INTO Signatures(signature) VALUES('$signatureDAT')");
    $sigID = mysqli_insert_id($dragonden);
    
    
    // RETRIEVE DATA FROM DB, TO VERIFY IT WAS SAVED PROPERLY
    $sigDAT = mysqli_query($dragonden, "SELECT signature FROM Signatures WHERE id = '$sigID'");
    
    
    // SEND RESULTS BACK TO AJAX
    $data = array();
    array_push($data, $signatureDAT, $sigDAT);
    print json_encode($data);
}
```

I then use ajax to retrieve `$sigDAT`

Ajax returns the following result for `$sigDAT`:
`[object Object]`
Ajax returns `$signatureDAT` (the original data) correctly.

`$sigDAT` and `$signatureDAT` should have identical value, so I suspect the problem is in the "RETRIEVE" section of code.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stucß Also, be warned that your queries are widely open for SQL injection

Comment: in ajax: instead of +data[1], I tried +data[1][0]... thinking it was maybe returning a multilayered array...

Comment: in php: instead of $sigDAT); i tried $sigDAT[0]);, and also sigDAT['signature']

Comment: yes, this is mainly for testing purposes at the moment, not live. I will worry about security once I'm getting ready to start using it.

Comment: Word of advice: Don't have a mindset of "*worry about security later*". Worry about it right away and do it right the first time - that way you don't forget it and leave your app vulnerable, you do it the right way the first time around, and don't have to go back and redo all your work later.

Comment: That is the wrong approach. Security should be built in from the start...that way you don't find you have to go back and change important parts of the code right before go-live, after you think you've built and tested it successfully. Then you have to test it all over again after the security changes. What a waste of effort. If you know there is a security issue, then simply do it properly the first time and then you don't have to worry so much. Prepared statements in particular are not really any extra effort to implement either, so there's no excuse not to use them.

Comment: _Side note:_ In JS, use `console.log()` to dump the javascript value (into the browser console) instead of `alert()` since the later won't show you the contents of objects and arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the security advice, I agree. I'm honestly not very experienced with mysql, and php for that matter, so this is pretty much a learning experience for me about some basics. security will be another learning experience. I'll bring these all together in a later project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to retrieve the results - `$sigDAT` in your code is an object of the class `mysqli_result`. However, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and you should therefor use a prepared statement to execute your queries. See the code below.

Also, if you set `mysqli_report()` to throw exceptions on error, you don't have to perform your subsequent select to verify that the query completed - because if an error occurs, an exception is thrown, and you don't reach the part where it adds the values into `$data`.

```php
// Make MySQL throw exceptions on error
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

if ($signatureDAT) {
    $data = [];

    try {
        $stmt = $dragonden->prepare('INSERT INTO Signatures(signature) VALUES (?)');
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $signatureDAT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $data[] = $signatureDAT;
        $data[] = $stmt->insert_id;
        $stmt->close();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        // An error occurred, handle that here 
    }
    print json_encode($data);
}
```